# How can I set up squid to act as a tunneling proxy to expose a VPN or SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel, tunneling, proxy

I'd like to set up a tunneling proxy accessible by URL--so, to access `bar.com` through the tunneling proxy, you'd go to `foo.com/bar.com` and continue to browse `bar.com` transparently from there.  I can either set up an SSH tunnel or a VPN connection that I'd like to expose.  How can I set up squid (or another proxy server) to route requests through an SSH/VPN connection like this?

Answer (score 2):

First, Setup your ssh tunnel

```
ssh you@yourproxysever -L8080:localhost:8080
```

Leave this connection running, this assumes that your proxy server is listening on port 8080.

Second, Setup your web browser to use localhost:8080 as its proxy server

The ssh tunnel will forward packets to your proxy server over ssh.

Comment: Use `ssh -fN ...` to make it drop into background after connecting.

Comment: Ohh, good point, I hadn't used that one.

Comment: Awesome; thanks!  How can I use this to expose that publicly?  I'm not exactly clear on how I would set up a webserver to receive a request (say, on 80), forward it to the SSH tunnel, and pass the response back.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear about what you need. But if you need to route web packets over SSH via a proxy, you can use SSH in SOCKS mode (`-D`) and use something like Privoxy in SOCKS mode to route it. So the connection would look like this:

```
[browser]---[privoxy proxy]---[ssh socks]---[remote machine]---[web server]
```

However, if you want to route traffic to a proxy via a SSH tunnel, you can use SSH in tunnel mode (`-L`) to route it something like this:

```
[browser]---[ssh tunnel]---[proxy on remote machine]---[web server]
```

Comment: So what I'd like to do is something like:
[browser]---[my webserver]---[ssh tunnel]---[proxy on remote machine]---[remote web server (whatever resource the user requests]

Comment: To finish that comment: it's not clear to me how to do that =)

Comment: In that case, your webserver would need to function as a reverse proxy with an upstream proxy configuration. You might be able to do it with some squid magic but I have a feeling that you will need to write your own server.